# Template 10 Error during setup Application Insight does not exist in Namespace

Tags: winrt-xaml, template10

I have followed the instruction to get the Template 10 up and running but I am running into a single assembly error CS0234

Error   CS0234  The type or namespace name 'ApplicationInsights' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)   WindowsApp1 C:\Users\Keshi\AppData\Local\Temporary Projects\WindowsApp1\App.xaml.cs

Any idea's why this assembly is missing.  I have installed the entire VS package.  Why would this assembly be missing.

```
        Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsAppInitializer.InitializeAsync(
        Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsCollectors.Metadata |
        Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsCollectors.Session);
```

Thank you

Comment: Do you simply need to add a reference to this assembling in your project?

Comment: I dont know where to find the assembly?  Any ideas. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

I had to add a few lines to the project.json file to solve this.  I believe the lines I added were (in dependencies):

```
"Microsoft.ApplicationInsights": "1.0.0", 
"Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.PersistenceChannel": "1.0.0", 
"Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsApps": "1.0.0",
```

My full project.json file looks like:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights": "1.0.0", 
    "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.PersistenceChannel": "1.0.0", 
    "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsApps": "1.0.0", 
    "Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform": "5.0.0", 
    "Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform": "5.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Uwp.Managed": "1.0.3",
    "Newtonsoft.Json": "8.0.2",
    "Template10": "1.1.*"
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "uap10.0": {}
  },
  "runtimes": {
    "win10-arm": {},
    "win10-arm-aot": {},
    "win10-x86": {},
    "win10-x86-aot": {},
    "win10-x64": {},
    "win10-x64-aot": {}
  }
}
```

And I can build and run the hamburger menu project (it's just the blank template as I'm just getting started).

Comment: Thanks. this solves the problem of unable to compile template 10 projects.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as of 5/18/2016 Template10 fails to build all of it project types out-of-the-box (Blank, Hamburger, Minimal) for all combinations of UW target/min versions because of the missing reference to application insights.

Direct change to `project.json` works fine, just as @CodingGorilla suggested.

Alternatively, in VS.Net you can add ApplicationInsights reference to Template10 project using NuGet console or via project drop down menu > `Manage NuGet Packages...` in the solution explorer.

In NuGet console:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsApps
```

Or

- Open project's NuGet Manager
- Switch to the Browse tab
- Search for Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsApps
- Install the package

NuGet will notify you that it installs the target and related packages, e.g.:

```
    Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.1.2.3 
    Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.PersistenceChannel.1.2.3 
    Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsApps.1.1.1
```

The "dependencies" section in `project.json` will be changed accordingly:

```
  "dependencies": {
     "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsApps": "1.1.1",
     "Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform": "5.1.0",
     "Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Uwp.Managed": "1.1.0",
     "Newtonsoft.Json": "8.0.3",
     "Template10": "1.1.*"
  },
  ...
```